# SDL joystick shooting angle c++

Tags: c++, 2d, sdl, game-physics, joystick

I'm having some issues with my shooting mechanics in my c++ 2D platform game using the SDL joystick. When I direct the joystick in any direction the bullet seem to go in the right direction-ish. When I do not direct the joystick in any dirction but press the shoot button I want the bullet to go in a horizontal line in the direction the player is facing( either 0 or -180), but right now the angle seems to be -108ish.

This is the code I use to get the angle of the joystick relative to the players position.

```
controller_y = SDL_JoystickGetAxis(j, 1);  // get controller y axis
controller_x = SDL_JoystickGetAxis(j, 0); // get controller x axis

int deltax = xpos - controller_x;          // diference in x pos
int deltay = ypos - controller_y;          // diference in Y pos

angle = atan2(-deltay, -deltax) * 180 / PI;
```

and in my update function I update the bullets position like this:

```
box.x += speed *(cos(angle*PI / 180)) * delta;
box.y += speed *(sin(angle*PI / 180)) * delta;
```

When I do not move the joystick in any direction the x and y value of the Joystick is usually lower 500 and bigger than -500. So my question is how I can get the bullet to go in the angle -180 if my player is facing left and I do not move the joystick and the angle 0 if my player is facing right when I do not move the joystick if that makes sense.

Comment: It'd be helpful to know how you represent the direction the player is facing towards. The `angle` here seems to be the direction of the spawned bullet.

Comment: I just have an enum, where LEFT is 0 and RIGHT is 1.

Comment: How does the player turn? Can the player only face LEFT and RIGHT as in, say, Mario?

Comment: What are `xpos` `ypos`? Which values are you getting for `deltax` and `delatay`? And i must say that these calculations seem to be more complex than they should be.

Comment: That is correct Jonas, since it's a 2D platform game it can only move left or right. The movement is based in the joysticks x axis, when event.caxis.value is above a certain threshold it will move right, and if it's below the negative of the same threshold it will move right.

Comment: VTT, xpos and ypos is the players position. When I'm standing stilland not moving the joystick deltay is around  1293-1000 and deltax is around 424 and 137. between those ranges.